# default.properties not being created

Tags: android, testing

I am using InteliJ Idea Community edition to develop android apps. I was trying to write UnitTests for a HelloWorld App as described in [link text](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html)
. However I keep on getting an error

```
Found main project package: com.example.helloandroid
Found main project activity: .HelloAndroid
Error: Unable to load the main project's default.properties
```

On going through the files that were created by InteliJ Idea, I saw that all the files as mentioned in `d.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html#CreatingAProject` are being created except for `defaul.properties` and `build.properties`.

Is there any way we can create these files?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you're describing as I'm also developing using IntelliJ and these are the steps I followed to create a valid `default.properties`

1) Create a project using Android (with no IDE) the instructions are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html#CreatingAProject). I created using exactly the same information than in my original IntelliJ project but looking at the resulting file it was not that important.

2) Copy the `default.properties` to your own project

In order to create the project you will have to know the id of the target you are using, you can obtain the list by executing `android list targets`.

Once I created the project I opened the `default.properties` file and the only thing important there was the target, in my case `Project target.target=android-8`

Hope this helps although your question is stackoverflow since a long time already.

Regards

PS: if I knew how to attach a file you wouldn't require to follow the above steps as the resulting file has no project specific information except for the target (if you want me to send it to you just tell me)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and has been fixed but the fix has not been released yet:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-69343?projectKey=IDEA&query=android+default.properties